# SVG path translate pivot point

Tags: css, svg, maps

I have a map with a marker, that I'd like to position to a particular coordinate with the path's translate attribute.

This would be the desirable result:

[image]

What I end up with is this:

[image]

The pivot point is always set to the upper left corner.
I can reset it from CSS with `transform-origin`, but only with hard coded px values (that does break if I change the SVG to something else).

If I use percentage values, the marker is positioned relative to the whole document.

Is there a way to set the pivot point, so that it always translates with it's bottom-center?

My SVG structure looks like this:

```
<svg>
  <path> MAP </path>
  <g>
    <path> MARKER </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```